# Edit with Wpbakery not working after Wordpress update

Tags: wordpress, wpbakery

I am in big trouble and I am losing my mind. I had to update wordpress, because woocommerce said I can't create variable products anymore. I did and then I noticed that Wp bakery is not working. It loads forever.

I read some topics and tried disabling guttenberg and installing classic editor. It didn't help..

Now the crazy part is that I exported project with all in one migration plugin to other server and it works... It takes a while but it works. How the hell it's possible ?

I still need to fix it and I am getting console error

Uncaught TypeError: window.vc.frame_window.jQuery is not a function
buildFromContent https://shop.marmoarc.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/frontend-editor.min.js?ver=6.2.0:10
build https://shop.marmoarc.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/frontend-editor.min.js?ver=6.2.0:10
 https://shop.marmoarc.com/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/js/dist/frontend-editor.min.js?ver=6.2.0:10

I really don't understand this stuff and already losing hair(okay I was losing regardless). Please help. :(

Comment: Did you purged all caches (if any)? Did you tried accessing from a Private/Incognito window in your browser? Did you tried updating WP Bakery plugin?

Comment: Yes, I purged all caches, tried on private and all browsers. Wp bakery is updated.  The only thing I found was why on other server exported project works fine.  [link](https://letsmakeiteasy.tech/how-to-fix-wpbakery-visual-composer-frontend-editor-not-working)    So I wrote my shared hosting provider to ask does he have Turn Off the Rocket Loader....

Comment: Im facing the same issue. did you find any solutions to it yet? @MindaugasPetraitis

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did, it fixes the issue but can cause certain other issues. For example my page banner doesnt load the first time a user visits the site, but will load every other time.

Get a plugin called **Enable jQuery Migrate Helper**. It seems to be the only thing that fixes the issue above that you've mentioned.

It will allow you to edit WPbakery elements, but like I said, it may cause other little issues like the aforementioned one above. Of course, if you're not using custom code, this could be the fix you're looking for. Cheers, and good luck.